# Apache ProxyPass with dynamic hostname

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Apache as a gateway to reverse proxy to a backend server with the same name as the requested http_host.

ex:

```
    ProxyPass            /  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
    ProxyPassReverse     /  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

I'm getting an error when I use this setup.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Apache ProxyPass directives with dynamic hostnames you will need to also use ModRewrite.

## Objective

All requests to the virtualhost will ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse (also known as an "Apache Gateway") to the %{HTTP_HOST}

The only reason this would make sense to do is if you have localhost entries on the apache server for specfic host names

## Examples

### Localhost File

```
10.0.0.2 foo.bar.com    
10.0.0.3 bar.bar.com
```

### How it works

1. The client makes a request to foo.bar.com (dnslookup is a public IP... YOUR APACHE SERVER)
2. Your apache server has a localhost entry of 10.0.0.2 for foo.bar.com (some other server on your network)
3. The request goes through ModRewrite and /path1 is appended, then handed off to ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse
4. ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse hand the call off to foo.bar.com at ip 10.0.0.2

Client requests foo.bar.com ---reverse proxies to----> foo.bar.com/path1 (on some OTHER internal server)

## Apache Configuration

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername *

    # Must not contain /path1 in path (will add /path1)
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path1/.*
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/path1$1 [NC,R=302,L]

    # Must contain /path1 in path (will send request to the proxy)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path1/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,P]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass            /  https://$1/
    ProxyPassReverse     /  https://$1/

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ###################
    # SSL Constraints #
    ###################

    SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1

    # Choose cipher suites
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXPORT

    # SameOrigin The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/gd_bundle.crt
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
</VirtualHost>
```

source: http://brakertech.com/apache-proxypass-with-dynamic-hostname/

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to dynamically reverse proxy like that using proxy pass. However, you can do it using mod_rewrite's `P` flag. The same thing with `ProxyPassReverse`, you can't use the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, *however*, since the hostnames are the same as the same, you don't need it at all. Just need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,P]
```

One issue you may run into is that since DNS resolves proxying server to some IP, the proxying server must know that the same DNS hostname does *not* resolve to itself and actually resolves to a backend server (the server to proxy *to*), otherwise it will cause a loop.